# Is MySQL IF equal to COALESCE?

Tags: mysql, if-statement, coalesce

Is

```
IF(CS2_PDM_D_Mini IS NULL,0,CS2_PDM_D_Mini)
```

equal

```
COALESCE(CS2_PDM_D_Mini),0)
```

Because of Postgres doesn't understand `IF`, I have plenty of MySQL `IF` statements into one SQL query, to transmute into a thing that PostgreSQL accepts

Comment: `select coalesce (Null,0)` this returns `0` and `select coalesce (2,0)` returns `2`, So the correct way is `select coalesce (CS2_PDM_D_Mini,0) from tbl`

Comment: OK thank you a lot, but does it prpduce the same result than the IF statement i've mentionned ? I think yes but not sure 100 per cent !

Comment: If you want to return **only** `0`(a single condition and to check for NULL) then it will work

Comment: Or If you want to handle multiple conditions you should use `case`. ie. `CASE WHEN condition THEN result
     [WHEN ...]
     [ELSE result]
END` , A simple [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+IF+alternative+for+postgresql&oq=mysql+IF+alternative+for+postgresql&aqs=chrome..69i57.10187j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) is enough to get an idea

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mock up Mysql `IF` format, use `CASE WHEN THEN END`, like here:

```
t=# select case when CS2_PDM_D_Mini  is null then 0 else CS2_PDM_D_Mini end ;
```

Check out [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-conditional.html) for both `CASE` and `COALESCE`:

> The COALESCE function returns the first of its arguments that is not
>   null

`IF` is [pl/PgSql statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html)